# Redirect main domain to subdirectory

Tags: htaccess, directory, site-url

Following the following code sample I managed to redirect it, however the site URL on the browser show as `domain.com/subdirectory` and not `domain.com`.

public_html ROOT `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

subdirectory `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN LiteSpeed
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN LiteSpeed` and `END LiteSpeed` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
# END LiteSpeed
```

Comment: Is WP installed in this subdirectory? The `.htaccess` code you posted is presumably in the document root? And you have another "WP" `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory? Have you also configured WP permalinks to omit `/subdirectory` from the URL?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Cannot see option to config WP permalinks to omit `/subdirectory` under settings>permalinks

Comment: Settings -> General

Comment: Gotcha. It seems to be the way. But, the admin returns 404 and the front end won't load any css/js.

Comment: What does the `.htaccess` file contain in the WordPress `/subdirectory`? Do you have any other directives in the root `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite I just edited the question and added the subdirectory `.htaccess`. Nothing else on the root `.htaccess` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the two `.htaccess` files you posted I can't see how your site is working at all?!

1. If you request `example.com/` (the document root) then the second rule in the root `.htaccess` file rewrites the request directly to `/subdirectory/index.html` (not `index.php`). If `/subdirectory/index.html` exists then the (non-WordPress) file is served, otherwise see #2
2. If you request `example.com/foo` (where `foo` does not map to a file or directory) then the first rule in the root `.htaccess` file internally rewrites the request to `/subdirectory/foo`.

   At which point the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory rewrites the request back to `/index.php` in the document root (not the subdirectory)! This either results in a 404, or a non-WordPress response, or ... you've have manually created `index.php` in the document root to somehow initiate WP?!

How you write these directives depends on whether you have another (non-WordPress) site in the document that still needs to be accessible. However, this would also change how you should configure WordPress as well.

For the sake of this example, I assume you only have the domain `example.com`, in which case there is no need to check the `Host` header (`RewriteCond` directive that checks against `HTTP_HOST`).

If you only have the WP site in the subdirectory and are serving no other files from the document root and you wish to completely "hide" the subdirectory then you can write your directives like this:

#### Root `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unconditionally rewrite everything to the subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

The `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory (below) prevents a rewrite loop.

#### `/subdirectory/.htaccess`

Either remove the `RewriteBase` directive altogether and remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or, (the "WordPress way"), hardcode the `/subdirectory`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

(The `RewriteBase` directive is not actually required in the above, but this is often how it is expressed in WordPress tutorials.)

Then, under Settings > General in WordPress, you would set both the "WordPress Address (URL)" (or `WP_SITEURL` constant) and the "Site Address (URL)" (or `WP_HOME` constant) to the site root `https://example.com` (no `/subdirectory`).

Comment: It worked on the frontend, but I cannot login to the admin anymore. Have any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: it works on frontend also i can login to backend but backend's styles not loaded